# dynamic dictionary to JSON problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, json

I'm currently working on a project using javascript and python with Jquery Datatables plugin and Django. My problem is that I am trying to create a dictionary in Python which I then wish to perform a json.dumps(dictionary) in order to send it across to the JQuery.

The conversion is performed and I can using a debugger see the data in the JQuery/Javascript code however it does not populate my table the reason being that the JSON is malformed. This I believe is due to the way the Dictionary in python code is created. I know I'm doing something wrong at this step. All the examples I've seen show a hard coded dictionary I need to create my dictionary dynamically. Here is the code I'm using in python. If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong please let me know this is driving me insane. This is the latest permutation of the dictionary code:-

```
    dictionary = {}
    array = []
    status = 'OFF'
    for item in self.scanResults:
        if item[6]:
            status = 'ON'
        else:
            status = 'OFF'

        array.append( {'MAC_ADDRESS':item['mac_addr'],
                    'IP_ADDRESS':item['ip_addr'],
                    'NAME':item['name'],
                    'OS':item['os'],
                    'OS_VERSION':item['os_version'],
                    'WORKGROUP':'--',
                    'STATUS':status
        })
    dictionary = dict({'aaData': array})
```

The JSON on the JQuery side should be in this format:-

```
{"aaData": [[..,..,..,..,],[..,..,..,..]]}
```

Cheers for any help you can provide

Chris

EDIT:

Additional information. Sorry for not including it earlier.
I'm encoding it the following way :-

return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict), mimetype='application/javascript')

The screen dump of results is:-

{"aaData": [{"STATUS": "ON", "WORKGROUP": "--", "IP_ADDRESS": "192.168.0.2", "OS_VERSION": "8.04", "MAC_ADDRESS": "00:10:e3:42:16:35", "OS": "Linux", "NAME": "Machine_One"}, {"STATUS": "ON", "WORKGROUP": "--", "IP_ADDRESS": "192.168.0.3", "OS_VERSION": "8.04", "MAC_ADDRESS": "00:19:a3:41:16:31", "OS": "Linux", "NAME": "Machine_Two"}, {"STATUS": "ON", "WORKGROUP": "--", "IP_ADDRESS": "192.168.0.4", "OS_VERSION": "8.04", "MAC_ADDRESS": "00:19:b3:43:16:32", "OS": "Linux", "NAME": "Machine_Three"}, {"STATUS": "ON", "WORKGROUP": "--", "IP_ADDRESS": "192.168.0.5", "OS_VERSION": "8.04", "MAC_ADDRESS": "00:19:c3:44:16:33", "OS": "Linux", "NAME": "Machine_Four"}, {"STATUS": "ON", "WORKGROUP": "--", "IP_ADDRESS": "192.168.0.6", "OS_VERSION": "8.04", "MAC_ADDRESS": "00:19:d3:45:16:34", "OS": "Linux", "NAME": "Machine_Five"}, {"STATUS": "ON", "WORKGROUP": "--", "IP_ADDRESS": "192.168.0.7", "OS_VERSION": "8.04", "MAC_ADDRESS": "00:19:e3:46:16:37", "OS": "Linux", "NAME": "Machine_Six"}, {"STATUS": "ON", "WORKGROUP": "--", "IP_ADDRESS": "192.168.0.8", "OS_VERSION": "8.04", "MAC_ADDRESS": "00:19:f3:47:16:38", "OS": "Linux", "NAME": "Machine_Seven"}, {"STATUS": "ON", "WORKGROUP": "--", "IP_ADDRESS": "192.168.0.9", "OS_VERSION": "8.04", "MAC_ADDRESS": "00:19:g3:48:16:38", "OS": "Linux", "NAME": "Machine_Eight"}, {"STATUS": "ON", "WORKGROUP": "--", "IP_ADDRESS": "192.168.0.10", "OS_VERSION": "8.04", "MAC_ADDRESS": "00:19:h3:49:16:41", "OS": "Linux", "NAME": "Machine_Nine"}]}

The actual epected results would be :-

{"aaData":[["ON","--","192.168.0.6", "8.04", "00:19:d3:45:16:34", "Linux", "Machine_Five"],
           ["ON","--","192.168.0.6", "8.04", "00:19:d3:45:16:34", "Linux", "Machine_Five"]]}
Just to give you an idea.

I'm using jQuery DataTables plugin for this. I beleive the problem is malformed dictionary ie: my fault. I'm new to python and have tried numerous permutations of dictionaries and have discovered 10+ ways not to do it I just need a hint to that elusive right way.

Cheers again

Chris

SOLVED:

I've solved the issue by passing back from the server an array of arrays (list of lists) if you prefer and parsing them on the client side due to the fixed size of the lists this is not causing a performance issue. I shall look more closely at this at a later date and post up a better fix or more elegant solution.

Comment: Are you doing `json.dumps(dictionary)`? What is the result of that? How is it different from what you're expecting? (I don't understand that expected output at all - please give some actual example data.)

Comment: Your values need to be in quotes

Comment: @meouw: They will be when serialized.

Comment: You have mixed subscript types: `item[6]` and item['mac_addr'] etc -- is this deliberate? correct?

Comment: Yeah item[6] is correct its just a nasty little reference which is to be modified later. Doesn't effect anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your question does not contain the key bit we need to see - how you are serialising your dictionary into a string. If you are just doing `str(dictionary)` then that will not work, you need to encoded it using [`simplejson`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/). You can install this library with easy_install, or if you're using Python 2.6+ then it's included as `json`.

To encode a Python object as a JSON string simple use `json.dumps(dictionary)`.

You say that your Javascript code is expecting an object containing nested lists, but your Python code seems to be generating an object like `{"aaData": [{..:.., ..:..},{..:.., ..:..}]}`, i.e. a dictionary, inside a list, inside a dictionary. If the problem isn't with how you're encoding the JSON string can be clearer about the object you're expecting?

**EDIT**

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams states in your Python code you're adding dictionaries to the list then expecting them to have magically transformed into lists when they're encoded as JSON. You either need to convert your Javascript to work with the data you are sending at the moment, or replace your current Python code with something similar to what Ignacio suggests.

I would suggest the first of these options as it is easy to get things wrong when using a list to represent a structure and you'll end up using the wrong value because you got the indexes wrong. If you keep it as a dictionary/object then you can access things by name and you avoid that problem.

Comment: Cheers I'll give it a go I was hoping for an elegant solution but perhaps a little parser on the javascript end wouldn't be too bad. At least I can come back to the problem at a later date. cheers

Comment: Cheers I opted for this approach its a work around but ok for now. I'll have to look again later at the problem when I have more time

Answer (score 2):

If it's malformed then you're malforming it. Did you mean:

```
    array.append([item['mac_addr'],
                item['ip_addr'],
                item['name'],
                item['os'],
                item['os_version'],
                '--',
                status
    ])
```

Comment: I really hope that he didn't mean that! The "expected data" e.g. `["192.168.0.6", "8.04", "00:19:d3:45:16:34", "Linux", "Machine_Five"]` looks like IP, os_version, MAC, os, name (different order) and doesn't have '--' and status

Answer (score 0):

The "expected data" appears to be **FIVE** items in a **LIST** (in a rather unexpected i.e. scrambled order); you are stuffing **SEVEN** items into a **DICT** -- **WHY??**

Take 2 (taking your unannounced edit into account):

The "expected data" appears to be seven  in a **LIST** (in a rather unexpected i.e. scrambled order); you are stuffing seven key:value items into a **DICT** -- **WHY??**

Are you sure that the expected data list should be in that scrambled order?

Comment: The expected data is just to give an idea of the format of the expected outcome.

Comment: @Chris Lamb: Five items in a list gives ABSOLUTELY NO IDEA that it should be seven items in a dict -- this is ridiculous!!

Comment: I'm sorry you feel its 'ridiculous', If you would have checked I actually amended it.

Comment: OK I'll apologise again, The unannounced edit was due to not having edited before on here and being a little to eager on the old submit button. The expected data was just for the use of format not content. I realise I should either have mentioned this or should have taken time to accurately depict the expected data. I shall do this in the future. Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0):

```
array.append([item['mac_addr'], # note: we are appending array.
              item['ip_addr'],
              item['name'],
              item['os'],
              item['os_version'],
              '--',
              status
            ])
```

when you serialize this, you get data in following format.
[["xxx","yyy","zzz"],["xx1","yy1","zz1"]] 
put that in dictionary, dictionary = {'aaData': array}

Comment: Your code fragment is NOT valid Python ...`[expression1:expression2]` is meaningful only when the expressions evaluate to sequence subscripts

Comment: I've already tried that and just tried it again both times Invalid syntax because that format item,item,. . . requires a list ie: { }. nice try anyways.

Comment: @Chris Lamb: **list i.e. {}** ??? Please try to understand this: `[]` is a list; `{}` is a dict.